# Zabbix trigger expression does not evaluate macro {HOST.HOST}

Tags: macros, zabbix

I am trying to create a Zabbix trigger that fires only when the current host is the owner of a ressource, but not the preferred owner. Two separate items are observing the current owner and preferred owner situation and are referenced by the trigger.

To accomplish this goal I created a trigger prototype with the following expression:
`find(/data/wsfc.ownernode[{#DATASTORE_NAME}],#1,"like","{HOST.HOST}")=1 and find(/data/wsfc.prefownernode[{#DATASTORE_NAME}],#1,"like","{HOST.HOST}")=0`

The low-level discovery macro are evaluated as expected, only the system defined macro does not.
The expression itself returns the correct result, when I manually replace `{HOST.HOST}` with the actual hostname.

As far as I understand the [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/5.4/en/manual/appendix/macros/supported_by_location), the macro should be evaluated as expected and the expression should work.

We are working with Zabbix server version 5.4.12 and will have to work with it for a while.

Does anyone know of a solution or workaround?
Ideally without any adjustments to the discovery script.